# Custom message for overflowed number during binding in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, type-mismatch

I have a web application wrote in Spring. There is a HTML form with one Integer field. I added a custom message for `typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer` and it is correctly handled but there is one issue. Spring does not distinguish between a string value and "overflowed" integer. In other words - there is no difference whether user enter `this is a string` or `1000000000000000000000000000`. Both are handled by Spring as `typeMismatch`. I would like to have two separate messages for both cases.

I thought about two solutions:

1. replace the `java.lang.Integer` by `java.math.BigInteger` in the
   form object - then the `typeMismatch` error will apply only to `this
   is a string` and I will handle `1000000000000000000000000000` in a
   validator
2. register my own property editor for `Integer`, but I'm not sure if I
   could handle two different errors with one property editor

Do you have any better concepts for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you integrate the hibernate validation framework / Java EE6 bean validation into your Spring project?

You could then limit the acceptable range allowed for your integer field with an annotation such as :

```
@Min(1)
@Max(10000)
private Integer myInteger;
```

Here is an easy to follow article :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5fd9bd/javax-annotation-and-hibernate-validator-a-pragmatic-appro/